Not allowing my site to be embedded elsewhere via oEmbed
Kind of "bizarre" question here.
Is there a way to disable the possibility of embedding (via oEmbed) my site elsewhere and instead having only the URL shown?
If you copy a URL into the block editor or in the visual editor, the site will be automatically embedded.
When someone does this with my site, I'd like to have only the URL displayed instead of the whole embedding thing (preview and so on).
Not sure if this is even possible. Any hint?
Thank you!

It is possible, but it would also disable embedding content on your site. Would that be an issue?

Yes, that would be an issue. Anyway, you mean if I disable oembed on my site then it won't be possible to embed it somewhere else?
